# Dump Trac DB on Windows/XAMPP

Tags: xampp, trac, sqlite

I have a Trac instance running on a WindowsXP machine with XAMPP. I am trying to migrate the trac instance to a newer Linux-based machine. However, I'm having a hard time getting the database to cooperate.

I try to dump the db with this command:

```
sqlite3 C:\tracroot\db\trac.db ".dump" >> mysqldump.sql
```

But the generated file is mostly empty:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
COMMIT;
```

So that's not right. For the record my trac instance is running now and appears to have full access to all the contents of the DB. But sqlite3 (located in C:\xampp\apache\bin) can't seem to get any information from the file. The DB file itself has the header "SQLite format 3", so that seems to be correct.

I need to know one of two things:

- How to get this dump working OR
- An alternate way to migrate the Trac database to the new machine.

**Update:** When I try to open the .db file in sqlite3, I get the error `Error: unsupported file format`. What format is it in, and why is it unsupported?

Answer (score 1):

My sqlite3 binary was apparently an older version and was backwards-incompatible with the version of the DB used by trac. I updated to the newer sqlite3 binary and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

apparently there are migration procedures to go through.

have you had a chance to look through http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMigrate

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're currently using sqlite as your backend database?  (Check your `trac.ini` for the `[trac]` `database = sqlite:db/trac.db` line.)  It may be that the db/trac.db you have is leftover from an initial setup, but the data is actually stored in another database.